# Using Trulia API in an Android app

Tags: java, android

I have a question about pulling data from Trulia api, and display it on an android app I am developing.  Essentially all I need is to be able to get the Home value and the Tax evaluation values.  The app will then be able to take these values and do what it's supposed to do. I have the apikey (trulia apikey), but I don't know how to communicate with the api so I can get the information I need.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the included Apache HttpClient in Android to make web service requests to their api. You can make the request and then parse the results using a SAX parser for speed.

See here : http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/package-summary.html